# How to stop `UIWebView` inside a `UITableViewCell` from reloading when dequeuing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

[Video of web view reloading after shown on screen](https://youtu.be/ZPyWAdxCNo0)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    if indexPath.row == 17 {
        let _cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "webCell") as! WebviewTableViewCell

        let webView = UIWebView()

        webView.frame = _cell.contentView.bounds
        webView.scalesPageToFit = true

        let webViewURL = "https://www.reddit.com/"
        var _request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: webViewURL)!)
        _request.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
        webView.loadRequest(_request)

        _cell.contentView.addSubview(webView)

        return _cell
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = "sample cell \(indexPath.row + 1)"

    return cell
}
```

I'm using the above code to provide a cached copy of the web view. However, every time the cell with web view is out of screen, the table view reloads the web view content. How to load the page only once inside the web view instead of loading it every time the cell goes off the screen? Any help would be greatly appreciated and up-voted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you are not using caching functionality of the `dequeueReusableCell` at all.
You are getting the cell from cache (queue) and then add a new web view to it.

Solution is to create a web view in `WebviewTableViewCell`'s `init`/storyboard.

Comment: I created a dedicated cell class and its counterpart in that tableView in storyboard. In `cellForRow` I'm using the `_request.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad` and still the page gets reloaded. Could you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = UITableViewCell()

if indexPath.row == 17 {
    let _cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "webCell") as! WebviewTableViewCell

    If _cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100) == nil 
{
    let webView = UIWebView()
       webView.tag=100;
    webView.frame = _cell.contentView.bounds
    webView.scalesPageToFit = true

    let webViewURL = "https://www.reddit.com/"
    var _request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: webViewURL)!)
    _request.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
    webView.loadRequest(_request)

    _cell.contentView.addSubview(webView)
}

    return cell;
}

cell.textLabel?.text = "sample cell \(indexPath.row + 1)"

return cell
```

}